# SQL server 2012, correção de ex

Tags: sql-server, join

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]verifiquem se a resposta do exercício abaixo está correta:

Liste os nome dos clientes (`Cli_Nome`) que possuem BÔNUS NÃO NULO
e que compraram produtos com código (`pro_codigo`) maior do que 5 e menor do que 10.

```
select c.cli_nome
from cliente c, pedido p, item i, produto pr 
where c.cli_codigo = p.cli_codigo 
and p.ped_numero = i.ped_numero
and i.pro_codigo = pr.pro_codigo 
and cli_bonus is not null
and pr.pro_codigo > '5' and pr.pro_codigo < '10'
```

Há alguma possibilidade de realizar uma "prova real" para identificar por conta própria se a questão está correta?

Comment: Tem sim. [Te apresento o SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: Obrigado, mas como seria a forma de verificação nesse SQL Fiddle? @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Comment: Você especifica as tabelas e os dados na parte de Schema (lado esquerdo), e executa seu comando do lado direito.

Comment: É uma boa, mas estou inciando ainda. Não sei criar as tabelas, apenas executar comandos com certa dificuldade. Mas obrigado, @CiganoMorrisonMendez, vc ajuda muito aqui, cara.

Comment: nessa resposta acima o not foi usado corretamente, ou está incorreto por não ser necessário? @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Comment: Estou montando um Fiddle pra você. Vou te pedir uns minutos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Montei este Fiddle pra você](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7f09b0/1). Devolveu o seguinte:

```
cli_nome
--------
Beltrano
Ciclano
Ciclano
```

Como teve repetição por causa dos produtos, precisamos usar [`DISTINCT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187831(v=sql.105).aspx) para trazer cada nome apenas uma vez, portanto:

```
select distinct c.cli_nome
from cliente c, pedido p, item i, produto pr 
where c.cli_codigo = p.cli_codigo 
and p.ped_numero = i.ped_numero
and i.pro_codigo = pr.pro_codigo 
and cli_bonus is not null
and pr.pro_codigo > '5' and pr.pro_codigo < '10';
```

Que traz:

```
cli_nome
--------
Beltrano
Ciclano
```

O Fiddle final, portanto, [fica assim](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7f09b0/2).

Os dados que usei foram:

```
create table Grupo (
  GRP_Codigo int primary key identity,
  GRP_Descricao char(30) not null
);

create table Produto (
  PRO_Codigo int primary key identity,
  PRO_Descricao char(50) not null,
  PRO_Preco numeric(9,2) not null,
  PRO_Apresentacao char(2),
  PRO_Quantidade int default 0,
  GRP_Codigo int foreign key references Grupo(GRP_Codigo)
);

create table Cliente(
  CLI_Codigo int primary key identity,
  CLI_Nome char(30) not null,
  CLI_Endereco char(40),
  CLI_Cidade char(20),
  CLI_Bonus numeric(9,2)
);

create table Pedido (
  PED_Numero int primary key identity,
  CLI_Codigo int foreign key references Cliente(CLI_Codigo),
  PED_Data datetime default getdate(),
  PED_ValorTotal numeric(9,2) default 0
);

create table Item (
  ITE_Numero int primary key identity,
  PED_Numero int foreign key references Pedido(PED_Numero),
  PRO_Codigo int foreign key references Produto(PRO_Codigo),
  ITE_PrecoUnitario numeric(9,2) default 0,
  ITE_Quantidade int default 0
);

-- Dados

insert into Grupo values ('Produtos de Limpeza');
insert into Grupo values ('Alimentos');
insert into Grupo values ('Bebidas');

insert into Produto values ('Detergente', 1.00, null, 50, 1);
insert into Produto values ('Pão Integral', 4.00, null, 50, 2);
insert into Produto values ('Refrigerante', 2.50, null, 50, 3);
insert into Produto values ('Sabão em Pó', 10.00, null, 50, 1);
insert into Produto values ('Queijo', 8.00, null, 50, 2);
insert into Produto values ('Vinho', 20.00, null, 50, 3);
insert into Produto values ('Saponáceo', 5.00, null, 50, 1);
insert into Produto values ('Biscoitos', 2.00, null, 50, 2);
insert into Produto values ('Água Mineral', 1.50, null, 50, 3);
insert into Produto values ('Limpa Vidros', 7.00, null, 50, 1);
insert into Produto values ('Chocolate', 6.00, null, 50, 2);
insert into Produto values ('Cerveja', 3.50, null, 50, 3);

insert into Cliente values ('Fulano', 'Rua Tal', 'Cidade Tal', null);
insert into Cliente values ('Beltrano', 'Outra Rua Tal', 'Tal do Sul', 12);
insert into Cliente values ('Ciclano', 'Uma Terceira Rua Tal', 'Tal do Oeste', 9);

insert into Pedido values (1, getdate(), 7.50);
insert into Pedido values (2, getdate(), 38.00);
insert into Pedido values (3, getdate(), 10.50);

insert into Item values (1, 1, 1.00, 1);
insert into Item values (1, 2, 4.00, 1);
insert into Item values (1, 3, 2.50, 1);

insert into Item values (2, 4, 10.00, 1);
insert into Item values (2, 5, 8.00, 1);
insert into Item values (2, 6, 20.00, 1);

insert into Item values (3, 7, 5.00, 1);
insert into Item values (3, 8, 2.00, 1);
insert into Item values (3, 12, 3.50, 1);
```

Comment: Agora ficou bem mais simples. Muito obrigado pela ajuda, brother.